# Filter out pure mysql query from procedure

Tags: mysql

using `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE GetWishlistFromToken`
it returns below data

'GetWishlistFromToken', '', 'CREATE DEFINER=`kortnick`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetWishlistFromToken`(\r\n IN userToken VARCHAR(255)\r\n)\n SQL SECURITY INVOKER\nBEGIN\r\n SELECT wi.product_id from `oauth_token` ot \r\n JOIN wishlist w ON ot.customer_id = w.customer_id\r\n JOIN wishlist_item wi ON w.wishlist_id = wi.wishlist_id\r\n WHERE ot.`token` = userToken AND ot.customer_id IS NOT NULL\r\n ORDER BY wishlist_item_id DESC;\r\nEND', 'utf8mb4', 'utf8mb4_general_ci', 'latin1_swedish_ci'

I am not sure how to filter pure mysql query from this

i have tried to use

SELECT wi.product_id from `oauth_token` JOIN wishlist w ON ot.customer_id = w.customer_id IN wishlist_item wi ON w.wishlist_id = wi.wishlist_id
WHERE ot.`token` = '11d587j0cks5jntb4lmr92t6e6efwk7z' AND ot.customer_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY wishlist_item_id DESC

but it shows error

```
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'wishlist_item wi ON w.wishlist_id = wi.wishlist_id WHERE ot.`token` = '11d587j0' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forget to copy the alias `ot` after `oath_token` and you also made a typo in one of the JOINSs. Try this:

```
SELECT   wi.product_id
FROM     oauth_token ot
JOIN     wishlist w ON ot.customer_id = w.customer_id
JOIN     wishlist_item wi ON w.wishlist_id = wi.wishlist_id
WHERE    ot.token = '11d587j0cks5jntb4lmr92t6e6efwk7z' AND
         ot.customer_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY wishlist_item_id DESC;
```

(And if '11d587j0cks5jntb4lmr92t6e6efwk7z' is really a token change it...)